# How to display data from database with multiple tables to data grid view?

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
 private void LoadData()
    {
        setConnection();
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
        string CommandText = "SELECT Rents.Name, Rents.Brand_Model_Plate_Number, Rents.rental_date,Rents.return_date,Car.rate,Payment.charges FROM Rents INNER JOIN Car ON Rents.rental_id = Car.car_id INNER JOIN Payment ON Rents.rental_id = Payment.payment_id; ";
        DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sql_con);
        DS.Reset();
        DB.Fill(DS);
        DT = DS.Tables[0];
        dgvBills.DataSource = DT;
        sql_con.Close();
    }
```

-\loads data :Only shows the column name but no data was shown

Comment: Is there definitely data in the table? Pause in the debugger, point to DT, click the magnifying glass. I suspect there will be no rows in the table; I've never known a DataGridView, bound in this way, fail to show rows when there are rows in the table. If there are no rows in the table, fix your joins or examine your tables in the db to check that they have data